# jQuery dataTable fail

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I'm use dataTable plugin. I fix this problem:

> table.row is not a function

(Use **D**ataTable() instead **d**ataTable())

It works:

```
function initTable(selector, ext)
{
    // merge defaults and extended settings
    ...
    // init plugin
    var table = $(selector).DataTable(params);
}
// call
initTable('#blah-blah', {...});
```

But I want cache variable (select one time) and use for others.

This is not working (table.row is not a function again):

```
function initTable(jqObj, ext)
{
    // merge defaults and extended settings
    ...
    // init plugin
    jqObj.DataTable(params);
}
// call
var table = $('#blah-blah');
initTable(table, {...});
// etc. reuse table
```

Return table object from initTable? Seriously? May be you known other way?

Comment: Pff-ha-ha! Working only this (inside function): var tableObj = $(jqObj).DataTable(params); but this is not true way..

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, you are passing some selector to make a new jQuery object and in the second function you are passing a jQuery object. So, I believe the problem is in another line of your codes because your second approach worked perfectly fine in this code sample:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function initTable(jqObj, ext)
    {
        jqObj.dataTable(ext);
    }
    // call
    var table = $('#example');
    initTable(table, {"sPaginationType": "full_numbers"});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6pvtarpc/

Comment: No, your answer is not useful. Problem only is "table.row is not a function" (for remove <tr>) Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6pvtarpc/1/

Comment: Because jqObj instance of jQuery, but not instance of DataTable

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote :/ Did you find any error on my code? Ans: no. I just used your code.

Comment: I think I have found your problem. You are using backdated datatable plugin for which this problem occurred. Quoting from upgrade page: `If you are upgrading from DataTables 1.9 or earlier, you might notice that a capital D is used to initialise the DataTable here. $().DataTable()  returns a DataTables API instance, while $().dataTable() will also initialise a DataTable, but returns a jQuery object.`

Comment: Nop. My bad. I used 1.9.0 so couldn't detect this. But the explanation is correct in the above comment.

Comment: I know it. But, I'm use v-1.10 and $('selector').DataTable() return DataTable instance, but where have jQuery object, this object implements DataTable() method, but not implements row() method. See my first comment after my question.